# Freebase API return raw JSON

Tags: json, api, freebase

The URL https://www.googleapis.com/freebase/v1/topic/en/alps returns a JSON string that is nicely formatted for reading. How can I tell Freebase to return the raw JSON string without all the unnecessary characters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make the API request with GZIP enabled which will get rid of ALL the unnecessary bytes.

```
Accept-Encoding: gzip
```

You can also use the [filter parameter](https://developers.google.com/freebase/v1/topic-overview#filter) to only return the property values that your app needs.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can, but it shouldn't make a difference to any JSON parser.  The whitespace isn't significant.